# Obj-C help resolving Retain Cycle in a block

Tags: objective-c, retain-cycle

I have a `BaseUnit` Class which has a method
`- (void)attackUnit:(__weak BaseUnit *)unit` 
Where it attacks another unit in a loop.

When only one unit attacks everything is fine and the dead unit get deallocated, but when both user attacks each other no-one get deallocated forever. I'm pretty sure I have a retain cycle in here.

I have a block inside this method which is getting called until enemy user is not dead (yeah... because he never deallocated :) )

I tried to use "weak - strong dance" but still no luck

Here is my code:

```
- (void)attackUnit:(__weak BaseUnit *)unit
{
    [self removeAllActions];
    [_unitNode removeAllActions];

    if (_unitType == ERangedUnit)
    {
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        __weak typeof(unit) weakUnit = unit;
        __weak typeof (self.parent) wekaSelfParent = self.parent;

        SKAction * action = [SKAction runBlock:^
                             {
                                 __strong typeof(weakUnit) refUnit = weakUnit;
                                 __strong typeof(weakSelf) refSelf = weakSelf;

                                 if ([refUnit isDead])
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"Attacking Dead Unit ");
                                 }
                                 if ([refUnit isDead] || !unit)
                                 {
                                     [refSelf removeAllActions];
                                     [refSelf->_unitNode removeAllActions];

                                     refSelf->_state = EUnitResting;
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {

                                     __strong typeof(wekaSelfParent) refSelfParent = wekaSelfParent;

                                     SKSpriteNode * projectile = [[ProjectileNode alloc]initWithTexture:_projectile.texture bitmask:_projectile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask];
                                     [projectile setScale:0.5];
                                     [refSelfParent addChild:projectile];

                                     CGPoint target = [refUnit.parent convertPoint:refUnit.position toNode:refSelfParent];
                                     [projectile setPosition:refSelf.position];

                                     [projectile setZRotation:AngleBetween(projectile.position, target)];

                                     CGFloat time = EuclidianDistance(target, refSelf.position)/400;
                                     [projectile runAction:[SKAction moveTo:target duration:time] completion:^
                                    {
                                        [projectile removeFromParent];
                                    }];
                                 //_state = EUnitResting;
                                 }
                             }];
        [_unitNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[_attackSpeedDelay, _attackBackAction, action]]]];
    }

    _state = EUnitAttacking;
}
```

When `projectile` hits a Unit this Code executes:

```
- (void)onHitBy:(__weak SKNode *)hitNode
{
    _currHp --;
    //Play some action.


    CGFloat hpFillHeight = CalculateHpFrame(_currHp, _hitPoints, _hpNodeSize.height);
    [_hpFillNode runAction:[SKAction resizeToHeight:hpFillHeight duration:0.2]];

    if (_currHp <= 0)
    {
        _isDead = YES;
        [_unitNode removeAllActions];
        [self removeAllActions];
        [self.delegate unitIsDead:self];

        [self runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]];
    }
}

CGFloat CalculateHpFrame(CGFloat value, CGFloat hpMax, CGFloat heightMax)
{
    CGFloat retVal;
    value = (value)/hpMax;
    retVal = value * heightMax;
    if (retVal<0)
    {
        retVal = 0;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Profiling with instruments show the following results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is certainly a classic way to get a retain cycle. Does the static analyzer tell you anything? If not, I would suggest using Instruments to track it down.

Comment: Analyzer says 0 issues found...

Comment: @matt instruments draws strange things I am not sure what it means... Will post a screen shot

Comment: SKMove is used under the hood by your SKAction `moveTo:`. Just as a test, remove that line and see if the leak goes away. (And is Instruments cool or what????)

Comment: @matt You are right, I removed the `moveTo` action and just called `[unit onHit:nil];`  -- Instruments stopped showing any leaks, However the log in `dealloc` method still not fires :(.

Comment: This suggests that there is no leak but someone is still retaining your object. You can turn on the Instruments feature where retains and releases are recorded, and so you can get a list of all the places where your object gets retained or released. You should be able to figure out (I sometimes have to use a pencil and paper) how these balance and don't balance, and thus who is still retaining your object. — Also in Xcode 8 you can use the unbelievably cool Memory Graph debugging feature to see who has a reference to your object.

Comment: I finally found my Problem, thank you very much sir, my problem was actually the _projectile(`SKSpriteNode`) as iVar... I thought I will make it once and copy for every Attack... Now I just simplified it with Retaining only the `SKTexture` and its bit mask for physics.  and Woalla I see the Deallocation Logs. (I heard Xcode8 will have a lot of cool stuff).
"(And is Instruments cool or what????)" -> Appears to be helpful ,but I wish it had better UIX -> it is hard to find things without google.

Comment: @matt I am a bit confused with all this weak - strong dance should I retain this code ?

Comment: `_projectile(SKSpriteNode)` as iVar — Yes, I was going to suggest that! Now I'm sorry I didn't. As for the weak-strong dance stuff: just try removing it and see whether the leak returns. I think it might, but if it doesn't, there's your answer.

Comment: @matt Yes I see, I definitely learned something new from all this stuff... Struggled on this about 2 days. Thank you for your suggestions sir!

Comment: You did great work on this. You can post your solution as an answer, and you can ultimately accept that answer. Could be useful to others!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense for `unit` to be `__weak` or for it to be used in the block -- you already have `weakUnit` and `refUnit` and you should be using that in the block instead. And it also doesn't make sense for `hitNode` to be `__weak` as it is never used.

Comment: @newacct Thanks I will keep that in mind.